# Python3 で multiprocessing の Pool を使うと遅くなるのはなぜ？

Tags: python, python3, python-multiprocessing

multiprocessingのPoolを使いましたが、使わないより遅いのはなぜでしょうか？

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
  return x*x

start = time.time()
with Pool(processes=4) as p:
  p.map(f,range(10))

print(f'time1:{time.time()-start}')

start = time.time()
a = [f(x) for x in range(10)]

print(f'time2:{time.time()-start}')
```

**結果**

```
time1:0.1648421287536621
time2:6.29425048828125e-05
```

**実行環境**
Python 3.7.0
macOS High Sierra
プロセッサ: 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5
メモリ: 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3

## **追記**

PicoSushiさんのご回答で、オーバーヘッドが原因ということがわかりました。sleepでmultiprocessingの効果を確認できましたが、データを増やして見ると、やはりmultiprocessingの方が遅くなります。
大量な計算を行う時にmultiprocessingを使わないほうがいいでしょうか？それとも他の方法がありますか？

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
  return x*x

start = time.time()
with Pool(processes=4) as p:
  p.map(f,range(10000000))

print(f'time1:{time.time()-start}')

start = time.time()
a = [f(x) for x in range(10000000)]

print(f'time2:{time.time()-start}')
```

**結果**

```
time1:2.1132028102874756
time2:1.4385631084442139
```

Comment: これも推測ですが、追記されたコードで結局fに掛かるコストがプロセスへの振り分けに掛かるコストより小さいのが問題に見えます。試しに、先程の自分の回答のように`f`に`time.sleep(0.001)`など挿入したところ、time2の方が大きくなりました。

Comment: @PicoSushi
なるほど、メソッドのコストが低い限りmultiprocessingの効果があまりないということですかね。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 原因

`time1`では、マルチプロセスにするためのオーバーヘッドが存在し、これが`f(x)`の計算コストに比べて大きいためと推測します。

## multiprocessingの効果を確認する例

f(x)の計算に1秒掛かる場合、を`time.sleep`で表現してみました。

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
  time.sleep(1)
  return x*x

start = time.time()
with Pool(processes=4) as p:
  a = p.map(f,range(10))

print(a)
print(f'time1:{time.time()-start}')

start = time.time()
a = [f(x) for x in range(10)]

print(a)
print(f'time2:{time.time()-start}')
```

結果

```
[1, 1, 4, 27, 256, 3125, 46656, 823543, 16777216, 387420489]
time1:3.034400224685669
[1, 1, 4, 27, 256, 3125, 46656, 823543, 16777216, 387420489]
time2:10.012826442718506
```